# KVO with custom class property

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

I want to use KVO in my application. I have one class property sizeForScrollView, when this property changed I want notification. I tried it but it was not working. Here is the code:

```
[self.aSubjectView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"sizeForScrollView" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.aSubjectView.sizeForScrollView.width, self.aSubjectView.sizeForScrollView.height);
        self.aSubjectView.frame = CGRectMake(frameForView.origin.x, frameForView.origin.y, frameForView.size.width, self.aSubjectView.sizeForScrollView.height);
}
```

Comment: If you want KVO, I suggest you check out ReactiveCocoa. It makes KVO a breeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.aSubjectView must be initialized and not be nil when adding the observer.

in observeValueForKeyPath you're currently just checking if self.aSubjectView is initialized but you should rather check

```
if  (object == self.aSubjectView)
```

try

```
[self.aSubjectView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"sizeForScrollView" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    if  (object == self.aSubjectView) {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.aSubjectView.sizeForScrollView.width, self.aSubjectView.sizeForScrollView.height);
        self.aSubjectView.frame = CGRectMake(frameForView.origin.x, frameForView.origin.y, frameForView.size.width, self.aSubjectView.sizeForScrollView.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i used 'frame' forKeyPath instead of 'sizeForScrollView' forKeyPath then it is working fine...so is there any limitation?

Comment: is aSubjectView's sizeForScrollView property ever set (sizeForScrollView = CGSizeMake(width, height) AFTER the observer was added?

Comment: is sizeForScrollView a readonly property being calculated from aSubjectView's frame properties? so the frame property should be observed instead.

Comment: what is difference between my code and your code?yes,i mean first i am adding observer and then changing size of sizeForScrollView.Initial value of sizeForScrollView is cgsizezero.

Comment: i have used assing property for sizeForScrollView

Comment: the code sample was related to your code before you edited. please provide more code to check.

Comment: Disagree with "you should also pass nil instead of null for context". `nil` would imply object `NULL` implies arbitrary pointer (which context is). Also, passing a context is a good idea.